# I'm using cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D in CUDA but I dont get correct answer!

Tags: debugging, cuda

This is my code, initializing a matrix d_ref and copying it to device. I'm not sure if I'm using cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D correctly but I tried to use [cudaMemcpy2D](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db.html) and bottom page 20 of [CUDA programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf)

All I get in output is 0.

What's wrong with my code? and is it the best way of doing this job?

Thanks in advance.

```
__host__    

float *d_ref;

float **h_ref = new float* [width];
for (int i=0;i<width;i++)
    h_ref[i]= new float [height];

for (int i=0;i<width;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<height;j++){
        h_ref[i][j]=ref_list[j][i]; //transpose
    }   
}

size_t ref_pitch;

cudaMallocPitch(&d_ref, &ref_pitch, width * sizeof(float), height);

cudaMemcpy2D(d_ref, ref_pitch, h_ref, width*sizeof(float),width*sizeof(float), height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


lowerBound<<<grid, block>>>(d_ref, ...




__global__ void lowerBound (float* d_ref, ....


    float* ref = (float*)((char*)d_ref + blockIdx.x * ref_pitch);

    cuPrintf(" %f \n",ref[threadIdx.x]);
```

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

> cudaMemcpy2D(d_ref, ref_pitch, h_ref, width*sizeof(float),width*sizeof(float), height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

why are you multiplying `height` by `sizeof(float)`?  You are transferring wayyy too much data!

Comment: True! Parameter height is not in bytes but the vertical linecount only

Answer (score 1):

The call to cudaMemcpy2D as written assumes that h_ref is a 2D-array of 'width' x 'height' float elements stored contiguously, when in fact it is a 1D-array of 'width' pointers.

Instead of representing the matrix as a 1D array of vectors, I would suggest storing it in a 1D array of 'width' x 'height' floats, and using macros for access based on row, column.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by adding a star next to h_ref in cudaMemcpy2D.   cudaMemcpy2D(d_ref, ref_pitch, *h_ref, width*sizeof(float),width*sizeof(float), hight, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

Comment: Please note that there are no guarantees that the individual column vectors pointed to by href[i] will be stored contiguously, so even after you change the code could still fail at any time.

Comment: okay! I still have problem with it. Apparently it doesnt copy correctly. I changed my definition of array from dynamic to static but still it's not working. I know changing to 1D is a solution but how can I use  cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D ? There should be a way of doing it in 2D...